# Is JIT a part of the PVM in PyPy?

Tags: python, jit, pypy

[image]

---

Is JIT a part of the PVM in PyPy?

---

Does JIT translates frequently used code into machine code and if that's the case then is the remaining code (apart from the frequently executed one) interpreted without converting it into machine code?

---

Is PyPy an implementation or an interpreter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is JIT a part of the PVM in PyPy?

A JIT compiler can be considered part of the virtual machine, yes. It's all a matter of definitions though. If someone else drew a picture where the JIT was represented as a separate component that's merely tightly integrated with the VM, I'd also accept that.

> Does JIT translates frequently used code into machine code

Yes.

> is the remaining code (apart from the frequently executed one) interpreted without converting it into machine code?

Yes, the bytecode will be interpreted until it has been executed often enough and the parts of the code that aren't executed often enough keep being interpreted.

> Is PyPy an implementation or an interpreter?

Interpreters *are* implementations of the programming language.

Comment: Just one question: *"Yes, the bytecode will be interpreted until it has been executed often enough and the parts of the code that aren't executed often enough keep being interpreted."* — Hey, is this only for a single program? I mean if the JIT compiler observes the same kind of pattern while executing a different program, will it execute the code directly by converting it into machine code? Does the JIT compiler recognize that pattern in a different program as well?

Comment: @Brobdingnagian It's for a single run of a single program. Once the program exits, the generated machine code disappears - it's not cached (see this [FAQ](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#couldn-t-the-jit-dump-and-reload-already-compiled-machine-code)). Doing this across common code between different programs would be even more difficult than doing it across runs of the same program.